# Unity FIrebase Sign In With Apple

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I want to use the Sign In With Apple in Unity , and use Firebase to manage my users.
I login my apple account successfully with my iphone.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T24ML.png)

I can only got the **info.idToken** , **info.userID** ,other info is not important(I guess)

In firebase ,it has a method for Sign In With Apple :
**Firebase.Auth.OAuthProvider.GetCredential(string providerId, string idToken, string rawNonce, string accessToken);  。**
providerId in doc is "apple.com"，idToken maybe the **info.idToken**，
but the rest 2 args i dont konw how to get.I'm the Client Developer,need i find help for server?

Comment: GetCredential(); with four args.the values are "apple.com",args.userInfo.idToken,args.userInfo.userId,null.Final,we can login in.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out the [Quickstart guide for Apple Sign-in with Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/apple#on-ios).
You'll see this sample:

```
Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.OAuthProvider.GetCredential("apple.com", appleIdToken, rawNonce, null);
```

The [reference pages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/o-auth-provider#class_firebase_1_1_auth_1_1_o_auth_provider_1a52b0fbf7d36822f090b2ce62d7405d31) also have a good breakdown of these arguments, I'll list them below:

- `providerId`: Name of the OAuth2 provider (in this case, `"apple.com"`)
- `idToken`: authentication token. (This is delivered from Apple sign-in after a successful login. You will not have this beforehand.)
- `nonce`: The raw nonce associated with the Auth credential being created. (this associates a session with an id, it's a safety measure)
- `accessToken`: The access token associated with the Auth credential to be created, if available. This value may be null. (it is `null`)

And a note that you need a separate plugin for the token and the rawNonce. You can [write your own native plugin to do that](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple) (this is Apple's documentation, it's a useful read), but I'd recommend just pulling in the [official Unity plugin](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/09/19/support-for-apple-sign-in/).